# How to retrieve CFStringRef values stored in CFArrayRef to an array of strings / char *

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I am new to cross platform programming.
I am facing an a problem here, but because of very limited online help ( or may be i do not know where to search ) I could not find a solution to it.

The problem is:
I want to convert a CFArrayRef to a usable format in C++/C
I have a CFArrayRef which holds language codes in CFStringRef format.
I want to retrieve it in some std::vector or C++ array of char*

Comment: C++ array of char*? That's absurd. If you use C++ then you should use C++ and make it an array of std::string.

Comment: I asked that just because CF lib is C based, So was just keeping the things very basic, I am aware that I can use some better container instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you have a CFArrayRef of some CFStringRef,
then all you have to do is to count the number of elements of vector,
Iterate on the CFArrayRef, get the string out of it and do whatever you want to do with it,
Here in sample code for an instance I am extracting elements of CFArrayRef and storing them in std::vector of std::strings.

Say here "names" is a CFArrayRef containing some names:

```
// Count of available names in ArrayRef
CFIndex nameCount = CFArrayGetCount( names );

std::vector<std::string> vecNames;

//Iterate through the CFArrayRef and fill the vector
for( int i = 0; i < nameCount ; ++i  )
{
    CFStringRef sName = (CFStringRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( names, i );
    strName = CFStringGetCStringPtr( sName , kCFStringEncodingMacRoman );
    vecNames.push_back( strName );
}
```

Comment: CFStringGetCStringPtr is not guaranteed to return non-NULL (and indeed often will return NULL). In order to use it safely you *must* have fallback code that uses CFStringGetCString if CFStringGetCStringPtr fails.

Answer (score 2):

CFString has this:
`CFStringGetCString`

Copies the character contents of a string to a local C string buffer after converting the characters to a given encoding.

```
Boolean CFStringGetCString (
   CFStringRef theString,
   char *buffer,
   CFIndex bufferSize,
   CFStringEncoding encoding
);
```

Parameters:
`theString`

The string whose contents you wish to access.

Comment: Hi uchuugaka,

Actually what I want here is to extract all the strings in CFArrayRef so that I can perform some actions on it,
Extracting C string from CFStringRef is not the problem..

Comment: So what's the problem? Writing C++ code? If you can extract one string, you can extract many strings.

Comment: OK. May be I am not putting the question correctly,
How can I extract all the CFStringRef present in a CFArrayRef.?

Comment: Seriously? If you're using Core Foundation, and you're comfy with C++ the docs and headers should be super easy to read. Have a look at CFArrayGetValues ( CFArrayRef theArray, CFRange range, const void **values ); and then look at CFArrayGetValueAtIndex ( CFArrayRef theArray, CFIndex idx );